# Recognize long press and pan gesture recognizers together

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view to which I've added both a pan and long press UIGestureRecognizer.  The pan is used to move the view around.  What I'd like to do is notice also that the touch has stopped moving (while remaining active) and trigger the long press.

What I find is that the long press is never triggered after the pan has begun.  I've tried setting a delegate and implementing:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"simultaneous %@", gestureRecognizer.class);
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"require fail %@", gestureRecognizer.class);

    return [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer self]];
    // also tried return YES;
    // also tried return [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer self]];
}
```

I've tried fooling with the pan gr's allowableMovement, also to no avail.  I'm just about to give up and use a timer in the pan gr that get's invalidated and then reset on moves, but I was hoping that the SDK would do the state machine stuff for me.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use the timer method (or something similar). The shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer: method isn't going to work, because the pan gesture recognizer should never get into the failed state in the scenario you propose. After moving, as long as your finger is still down, I think the pan gr will still be in the state, UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged.

Comment: Did you add the long press gesture recognizer in the view?

Comment: @mownier, thanks.  Yes I did.  I had to roll my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anyone else needs it, here's the code that works for me.  The goal is to have a view that is sensitive to both long press and pan, including a long press that isn't preceded by a pan and vice versa.

```
// setup
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;          // triggers the long press during pan
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *longPressView;   // need this to track long press state

// view is the view we're interested in panning and long pressing
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGR:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:panGR];

// this starts a long press when no pan has occurred
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGR = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGR:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:longGR];
```

When a pan begins or changes, start a timer.  If the timer expires before the pan ends (touch releases), then we have a long press.

```
- (void)panGR:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self startTimer:gr.view];
    } else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [self startTimer:gr.view];

        // do whatever you want to do with pan state in this method
        // in my case, I'm translating the view here

    } else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (self.longPressView) {
            [self longPressEnded];
        } else {
            [self.timer invalidate];
        }
    }
}
```

We give the timer user info of the view.  You might need to store other parts of the gesture state, like location, etc.  Do it the same way, with the user info dictionary.

```
- (void)startTimer:(UIView *)view {
    if (self.longPressView) return;
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self
                                                selector:@selector(longPressTimer:)
                                                userInfo:@{ @"view": view} repeats:NO];
}

-(void)longPressTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {

    self.longPressView = timer.userInfo[@"view"];
    [self longPressBegan];
}
```

Since the timer method won't have an associated gr, factor out all of the logic that we'd normally put in the gr handler so it can be called by both the timer handler and the gr handler.

```
- (void)longPressGR:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.longPressView = gr.view;
        [self longPressBegan];
    } else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self longPressEnded];
    }
}

- (void)longPressBegan {
    NSLog(@"long press began");
}

- (void)longPressEnded {

    self.longPressView = nil;
    NSLog(@"long press ended");
}
```

Comment: Does this allow a pan gesture to be detected if preceded by a long press? So if a long press is detected, the user does not remove their finger from the screen and then attempts a pan gesture?

Answer (score 0):

First of we have to register both long press and pag gesture events like,

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
longPress.delegate = self
longPress.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessageLongPress(_:)))

let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
panGesture.delegate = self
panGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessagePanGesture(_:)))

self.imgRecord.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
self.imgRecord.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

then we have to setup to capture multiple touch events via delegate method. For this we have to extend **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** and then use,

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

then we can implement events as we needed.
(in my case I wanted to cancel recording audio if user swipes, then I had to consider about touch started point and touch ended point as needed.)