# Executing pan gesture recognizer ONLY after long press recognizer has fired

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop UI for my UIView using the pan gesture recognizer. I have that piece of code working, but now I want to only execute the drag and drop logic only AFTER the user has long pressed on my to-be-dragged view.

I'm implementing the code in the below question
[Recognize long press and pan gesture recognizers together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026047/recognize-long-press-and-pan-gesture-recognizers-together) but it's not exactly what I want. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Set up your view controller as the delegate of the pan gesture recognizer.

Implement the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` method. Return false until after the long press gesture recognizer fires.

Comment: Do I just keep a flag somewhere in my VC to see if the long press gesture has started? Or is there a better way?

Comment: A flag seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Found another post whose title was a bit misleading so I didn't look into it too much the first time.
[Combine longpress gesture and drag gesture together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272333/combine-longpress-gesture-and-drag-gesture-together)

It turns out, `UILongPressGesture` already can help me achieve the drag and drop effect that I want. That means I do NOT need the `UIPanGesture` at all. I just used selector/handler for the pan gesture for the long press gesture. Except the long press gesture doesn't have the `translation` properties, so I use

```
myView.center = sender.location(in: myView.superview)
```

to achieve the same dragging effect.